# Content is not appearing in PlaceHolder?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the below Place holder between the head tags on a master page which all pages at some stage inherit from:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphHead" runat="server" />
```

I then have the below content on a page that inherits from the master page:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphHead" Runat="Server">    
    <asp:Literal ID="litMetaTitle" runat="server" />
    <asp:Literal ID="litMetaDescription" runat="server" />
    <asp:Literal ID="litMetaKeywords" runat="server" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="CphHeaderContent" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

As you can see this has another place holder in it, from this page inherits another page with the below content:

```
<asp:Content ID="ContentHeader" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="CphHeaderContent">
    <asp:Literal ID="TheId" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

The literal is being built with a string builder in the code behind:

```
private void xxx(Order order)
{
//...Building string with string builder
TheId.Text = xxx.ToString();
}
```

This literal is not appearing in the head of this page when I view it in the browser? Does anyone have any idea as to why? If I add something like below between the content tags:

```
<asp:Content ID="ContentHeader" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="CphHeaderContent">
    <asp:Literal ID="TheId" runat="server" />
    <script src="/Media/Javascript/xxx.js"></script><--ADDED!
</asp:Content>
```

The `<script src="/Media/Javascript/xxx.js"></script>` will appear in the head? Its just the literal that wont? Why is this?

Comment: CphHeaderContent is the last element, why don't you seperate them?

Comment: Sorry can you explain what you mean?

Comment: Dont worry found the issue, it lay somewhere else in which something was happening causing the method building the string not to be called!

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer to the question, Srb1313711.

Comment: I can do but the solution doesnt really have anything to do with the question, its a seperate issue that was causing the one in question to arise.